# Extend the index of an existing dataframe and fill new missing values

Tags: python

I have a df with two columns: "hour" and "transactions"

```
    hour  transactions
 0   10    792
 1   11    792
 2   14    594
 3   15    198
 4   16    198
```

The first row basically means that from 10:00 to 10:59 there were 792 transactions. If nothing happened in a certain hour, the entry was never made.

I need to fill in all the rows for 24 hours like this:

```
hour       transactions
0          0
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
6          0
7          0
8          0
9          0
10         792
11         792
12         0
13         0
14         594
15         198
16         198
17         0
18         0
19         0
20         0
21         0
22         0
23         0
```

I have tried this:

```
new_index = pd.Index(np.arange(0,24,1), name="hour")
df4.set_index("hour").reindex(new_index).fillna(0)
```

but when I print the df it still looks like this:

```
     hour    transactions
0    10      792
1    11      792
2    14      594  
3    15      198
4    16      198
```

Comment: What happens if you do: `df4 = df4.set_index("hour").reindex(new_index).fillna(0)`?

Comment: Hahaha, omg you're right. I didn't save it xD